# Drop all logins where loginname like 

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to bulk remove users from a database with a script for every login with a name that matches a certain pattern.  What is the best way to do this with TSQL?

`DELETE syslogins WHERE....` does not work

Trying to delete straight from syslogins will return "Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this query to create your TSQL statements? Then copy this SQL into a new query and exec.

```
select 'drop login [' + name + '];'
from sys.server_principals 
WHERE name like 'foo%'
```

This is basically the script that'll be created and run when you delete/drop a login from SSMS.

Comment: Thanks p.  If nothing better comes along I'll do it this way.  I was hoping to avoid the loop, but if it can only be done one at a time that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 4):

```
USE MyDatabase

DECLARE @LoginName sysname
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE DBLOGINS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals
    WHERE name LIKE 'some_pattern%'

OPEN DBLOGINS

FETCH NEXT FROM DBLOGINS INTO @LoginName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'DROP LOGIN [' + @LoginName + ']'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    FETCH NEXT FROM DBLOGINS INTO @LoginName
END

CLOSE DBLOGINS
DEALLOCATE DBLOGINS
```